# Navigating through pages in SWT Browser

Tags: java, browser, swt

I am developing a java application using SWT which has an embedded browser.I need to navigate back and forth as in a regular browser.I know there are browser.back()  and browser.forward() functions.But the problem is i am not setting the content of the browser using URL's,instead i am constructing a string and setting it to browser using browser.setText() . So the back() and forward() functions are not working!.The best solution i have thought is to have a list/array of strings to store all the strings used to set the content of the browser and use it to navigate.Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you not store the html content in actual (local) HTML files and use those?

Comment: Do you mean,i write the string to a file and give its url to browser?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: But il have to delete those files at the end.This involes saving all the file names i have created and deleting them at end.Is there no other way?

Comment: Ah, so it's dynamically created content. Then I'm not aware of another solution (other than the two mentioned).

Comment: The Eclipse internal class `BrowserViewer` does something like this using the browser `LocationListener` listener. It just uses a list of locations.